# Apache Airflow - ExternalTaskSensor,how do we use 'execution_date_fn' to return execution_date

Tags: airflow

If the upstream dags are triggered dynamically, they are assigned granular 'execution_date' rather than `dd-mm-yyyy hh:00:00` as the scheduler would assign. In this case we would need to implement an 'execution_date_fn' in sensor that looked through the metadata db to find the exact execution time to poke the status.

We need to check/test if this can be implemented for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example in my case.

```py
import pendulum

def get_execution_date(dt):
    print('Original execution_date: ' + str(dt))
    return pendulum.datetime(2019, 5, 11, 11, 36, 54, 894008)
```